Convolutional autoencoder from Mel spectogram . Does not work
enter image description here
# Convert list to a numpy array
data_array = np.array(data_list, dtype='float32')
data_array = np.array(data_array, dtype='float32') / 255.0 # so my data is from 0 to 1 
import os
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time
from keras import regularizers

train_images, test_images = train_test_split(data_array, test_size=0.1)  # 10% for testing 
train_images, val_images = train_test_split(train_images, test_size=0.1)  # 10% of the rest for validation

print(f'Train set size: {train_images.shape}')
print(f'Validation set size: {val_images.shape}')
print(f'Test set size: {test_images.shape}')

# Hyperparameters correct or close to correct? parameters based on paper.
H, W, C = 256, 256, 1  # 1 fro arraxy np b&w
learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 16
epochs = 50 #Random Epochs
latent_dim = 128  # to understand

l2_reg = regularizers.l2(1e-4)

inputs = Input(shape=(H, W, C))
x = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((4, 4), padding='same')(x) #fixed pooling 
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((4, 4), padding='same')(x) 
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  

# X is my ouput from the last layer

# Bottleneck operations with respect to X\
bottleneck = Flatten()(x)
bottleneck = Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(bottleneck)  #  latent space (LS)
bottleneck = Dropout(0.3)(bottleneck)  # Apply dropout for regularization
                                       #output is bottleneck
#Decoder
x = Dense(8* 8* 128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(bottleneck)  
x = Reshape((8, 8, 128))(x)  
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)  
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = UpSampling2D((4, 4))(x) 
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = UpSampling2D((4, 4))(x)  
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
#Padding ?
#x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((2, 2), (14, 14)))(x)  #  size requirements?
# Final Reconstruction
outputs = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(x)   # modified 1 becuase there was a 3  : before and it did not make sense, why sigmoid
#Sigmoid = values between 0 and 1 
#or Relu


# Full AUTOENCODER model
autoencoder = Model(inputs, outputs)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae']) # or mse
 


# Model architecture
autoencoder.summary()
print(train_images.shape, test_images.shape)

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

#early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
# train_images, val_images are preloaded in at the begining of the CAE

history = autoencoder.fit(
    train_images, train_images,  # inputs and targets
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True, #True
    callbacks=[tensorboard], 
    validation_data=(val_images, val_images),  #validation_data=(val_images, val_images)
)
# Generate reconstructions
rec_images = autoencoder.predict(val_images)[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/4g01e.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/trl9d.png)

I have 2550 audio files of 2 seconds which i applied Mel spetogram, using only the np array data i have feed my CAE with these dimentions 2562561. I have applied early stopping, Active learning and regulatization L2 in order to improve my NN learning, but i dont know why it is not working. i dont have a lot os experience wíth NN and i would like to understadn what i am doing wrong along the NN. i will attached here the  code and results. Thanks in advance if you want to share your similar expeeriences and solution to these problems. enter image description here
